# Trigger any Actor by Line Trace

Tags: function, triggers, actor, blueprint, unreal-engine4

I want to trigger a standard function for all actor who get triggered by the Line Trace Function.

Thats my function to find the Actor, that works.

[Blueprint](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3966/h9igyd9u_png.htm)

Now i want to trigger a function like "clicked" or something in the Actor.

On the Unreal Doc is a [TickActor()](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/TickActor/index.html) but it like seems i can't access this function.

Is there any predefined function to trigger an actor?

Comment: What do you mean with "trigger an actor"? You can only call blueprint functions that you must spcifically declare on each actor you want to call the function on. Alternatively, you can implement an event dispatcher with custom events (see https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Blueprints/UserGuide/EventDispatcher/index.html ).

Comment: I want something like the "Destroy Actor" function.
Just like i go to any wall, press e, and the next object in my line trace is destroyed. But i just want to trigger "any" object. 

The idea is like grabbing items from the ground and other stuff. I really don't want to bind every single Item as Actor to the line trace function.

*edit
I will watch over the dispatcher when i'm home, Thank you (:

Comment: Then you have to cast your hit result to something more specific than actor. Actor is the base class for all your blueprints you place in the world, so there is no "trigger" function on actor that you could call.